# What's wrong with using df.loc to assign new values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do suppose the following two functions generate the same results:

```py
import pandas as pd
def test_fn1(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
    return df

def test_fn2(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
    return df
```

`test_fn1` works as expected:

```py
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [{'c': 1}, {'c': 2}, {'c': 3}]})
test_df

a   b
0   1   {'c': 1}
1   2   {'c': 2}
2   3   {'c': 3}
```

```
test_fn1(test_df)
    a   b
0   1   [{'c': 1}]
1   2   [{'c': 2}]
2   3   [{'c': 3}]
```

Somthing wrong with `test_fn2` which uses `.loc` to assign values:

```py
test_fn2(test_df)
a   b
0   1.0 [{'c': 1}]
1   2.0 [{'c': 2}]
2   3.0 [{'c': 3}]
b   NaN NaN
```

What causes the last row?

Comment: update column with loc would be `.loc[:, 'b']`.

Comment: what does it mean `->` in `def test_fn1(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:`?

Comment: @Mario You mean [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a single label to `df.loc`, it is treated as an index label (see "Setting Values" in the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)). Thus `df.loc['b'] = ...` assigns to a row of the dataframe with index value `b`. You need to assign to the `b` *column*, so you need to specify that you want to fill all row addresses, which you do with `df.loc[:, 'b']`.

```py
import pandas as pd
def test_fn1(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
    return df

def test_fn2(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.loc[:, 'b'] = df['b'].apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, dict) else x)
    return df

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [{'c': 1}, {'c': 2}, {'c': 3}]})

test_fn1(test_df)
#    a           b
# 0  1  [{'c': 1}]
# 1  2  [{'c': 2}]
# 2  3  [{'c': 3}]

test_fn2(test_df)
#    a           b
# 0  1  [{'c': 1}]
# 1  2  [{'c': 2}]
# 2  3  [{'c': 3}]
```